# how to use input tage to upload image and view preview of file uploaded in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, file-upload

I want to give facility of uploading an image, preview of it and storing image to specified folder in laravel after submitting form by user .

I know the basic that I will be able to get browse button by

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="img">
</div>
```

by this I am getting file, now how can I make this image visible as preview.
I also need to upload this image to asset/image folder in my laravel project

Comment: What have you attempted to make work?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to require php for that.
check this out : [How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766/Web-Developer-How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP.htm)